# Create ability radius Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a unity game's ability system in which some of the spells have specific range, I'm not quite sure how to do that but here's what i camed up with.

1. I will need some sort of sphere which will be invisible and the center of it will be my character.
2. The radius of the sphere will be equal to the range of the spell selected.
3. My spells are being cast over the mouse position which means i will be able to check if the sphere is colliding with the mouse.

Overall this idea with the sphere seems good to me because later on i will be able to add color to it so the user can also see the phsycal range of the spell if he want's to. But i see a few problems :

1. The mouse is moving only in 2 dimension x and y however for a 2D object collission to be detected the method requires another 2D colider, well the sphere is 3D.

   ```
   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
   {

   }
   ```
2. I'm not sure how to make let's say 500 pixels range to be still relative to my screen and therefore this to be the actual radius of the sphere because my characters dont seem to move huge distance when i'm looking at the x axis, they move just a tiny bit and making a sphere with radius of 500 on the x axis will be complete disaster.

As i said I'm not sure how to make this, I'm new to unity and i'm not sure how to implement my idea, so any help or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to project your mouse in 3D to do the collision check. (You can imagine your mouse shooting a line right in front of it) You can do that using raycast:

```
RaycastHit hit; 
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
if ( Physics.Raycast (ray,out hit,100.0f))
{
     if(hit.collider == yourSphereCollider)
     {
         // the mouse was pointing at the sphere
     }
 }
```

Note that if there is another collider between the sphere and the mouse, it will be detected instead.

You can also use the same technique to determine where on the ground your effect should be displayed

Comment: Can you enchance your answer by adding some tag checking ? I think this will fix the problem *if there is another collider between the sphere and the mouse, it will be detected instead.*

Comment: No need for tag check: the line `if(hit.collider = yourSphereCollider)` will prevent the detection of any other  object. An object between the mouse and the screen will be discarded by this if statement.